# Saving temporary data in MVC5 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to save the data from the registration page temporary. If the admin verifies the user, I want to move the data to the database, else the data should be deleted after a time. What do you recommend for that? I read about Tempdata and session but I don't know if they are best practice for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The data will need to be stored on the server for availability by other users (admin) so I would suggest using a database.

If a user registers, store the data (all the registration fields etc) with a boolean property for instance Verified = false.

These users can be listed for the admin to approve, once approved, set Verified = tree, in this case the is all you need to do and you data is where it should be.

Comment: But if I store all the people who registered, I will have very big data and I won't use except the verified one

Comment: If they are verified, you will want the data, if not you can delete the data?